# T-SQL ошибка " В базе данных уже существует объект с именем "#t2". "

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите, мб кто сталкивался, почему данный запрос выдаёт сие сообщение, в предпоследнем запросе я её явно дропаю, и именно на последнем запросе выдаёт ошибку. Если выполнять все запросы по отдельности, то всё ок

```
drop table #t1
select p.ID as PID,pp.id into #t1 FROM tmp_for_attach t
inner join people p on t.enp=p.enp--t.
fam=p.fam and t.IM=p.IM AND t.OT=p.OT AND t.DR=p.DR
inner join POLIS PP ON P.ID=pP.PID
WHERE (stage = 1) AND t.opdoc=3
order by p.id,pp.ID

drop table #t2
select p.ID,MAX(pp.id) as maxpolid into #t2 FROM tmp_for_attach t
inner join people p on t.enp=p.enp--t.fam=p.fam and t.IM=p.IM AND t.OT=p.OT AND t.DR=p.DR
inner join POLIS PP ON P.ID=pP.PID
WHERE (stage = 1) AND t.opdoc=3
group by p.id
order by p.id

delete from #t1 where id in(select #t2.maxpolid from #t2)

drop table #t2

select PID,MAX(id)as id into #t2 from #t1
group by pid
order by pid
```

Comment: `BEGIN TRANSACTION;
select 1 as id into #t1
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
select 2 as id into #t2
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
drop table #t2
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
select id into #t2 from #t1
COMMIT TRANSACTION;`

тестовый пример, та же ошибка...

Comment: Решит проблему `go` после `drop table #t2`. / А вот как лаконично объяснить... Может, профи подтянутся.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov есть предположение, что SQL может менять порядок инструкций выполняя оптимизации...

Comment: Временная таблица удаляется после завершения сессии. То есть имя таблицы остаётся занятым до конца сессии, несмотря на дроп. Как-то так.

Comment: Да, GO помогло, спасибо Alexander Petrov